# jQuery overlay plugin

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

I am building a small overlay plugin to use for upcoming projects, the following code works with a bit of imperfection:

```
  $(document).ready(function()
    {

        var clickable_link = $('.p_wrapper p'),
            overlay = $('#overlay'),
            close_overlay = $('.close_overlay');

        clickable_link .click(function(evt){
            evt.preventDefault();
            //if there is no content
            current_link = $(this).attr('class');
            var overlay_content = $('#'+current_link);
            overlay.children().fadeOut(500, function(){
                overlay_content.fadeIn();
            });
            overlay.fadeIn();
        });

        overlay.click(function(){
            overlay.fadeOut();
            overlay.children().fadeOut(500);
        });
    });
```

If I click the first time on 'clickable_link' it's all good, but if I keep the overlay opened and then click again on 'clickable_link' the first content of the overlay fadesOut and then the new one fadesIn but one after the other not at the same time (which would look nicer and smoother) [Full code here](http://jsfiddle.net/PWV3q/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the last clicked link : http://jsfiddle.net/PWV3q/15/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var clickable_link = $('.p_wrapper p'),
        overlay = $('#overlay'),
        close_overlay = $('.close_overlay');

    overlay.hide();
    var lastLink = null;
    clickable_link.click(function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        if (lastLink != this) {
            lastLink = this;
            //if there is no content
            current_link = $(this).attr('class');
            var overlay_content = $('#' + current_link);
            overlay.children().fadeOut(500, function () {}).promise().done(function () {
                overlay_content.fadeIn();
            });
            if (!overlay.is(':visible')) overlay.fadeIn();
        }
    });

    overlay.click(function () {
        overlay.fadeOut();
        overlay.children().fadeOut(500);
    });
});
```

Comment: Ok, it is because children returns 3 elements, then 3 fadeout complete callback are called => overlay_content.fadeIn() occurred 3 times. Check my last update

Comment: Great it works nicely but how does the 'promise' work in this case?

Comment: The done function is only called when all fadeout callbacks have been executed.